# Making ZeroDivisionError print out a string of text

Tags: python

I have to create this average procedure..

```
def averageyield(cowcodes,milking):

    for code in cowcodes:
        count=0
        total=0
        for yields in milking:
            if (yields[0]==code):
                total=total+yields[1]
                count=count+1
        average=total/count
        taverage=round (average,0)
        print (code+" average is "+str(average))
```

When the count is 0 I get a ZeroDivisionError. I want to make that error output a message that prints some sort of string.

Comment: did you tried try/except ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement

```
if count != 0:
    average = total / count
else:
    print('Count is 0')
```

or use `try`

```
try:
    average = total / count
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Count is 0')
```

Comment: why this   if count !=0:, we can simply write if count:, As python is made to do less code :)

Comment: @GautamJangid *"Explicit is better than implicit."*

Comment: Great!, Thanks :)